# Python: how to terminate a function of a script from another script

Tags: python

I have a script `main.py` which called a function `fun` from a library.
I want to exit only from `fun` continuing the script `main.py`, using for this purpose another script `kill_fun.py`.

I tried to use different bash commands (using os.system) with `ps`, but the pid it gives me is referred only to `main.py`.

Example:

-main.py

```
from lib import fun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        fun()
    except:
        do_something
    do_something_else
```

-lib.py

```
def fun():
    do_something_of_long_time
```

-kill_fun.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    kill_only_fun
```

Comment: Can you please add more specifics like the sample of code, what you already tried and what challenges are you facing ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advices. I edited my question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by run `fun` in a different process.

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from lib import fun

def my_fun():
        tmp = 0
        for i in range(1000000):
                sleep(1)
                tmp += 1
                print('fun')
        return tmp

def should_i_kill_fun():
        try:
                with open('./kill.txt','r') as f:
                        read = f.readline().strip()
                        #print(read)
                        return read == 'Y'
        except Exception as e:
                return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        p = Process(target=my_fun, args=())
        p.start()
        while p.is_alive():
            sleep(1)
            if should_i_kill_fun():
                p.terminate()
    except Exception as e:
        print("do sth",e)
    print("do sth other thing")
```

to kill `fun`, simply `echo 'Y' > kill.txt`

or you can write a python script to write the file as well.

*Explain*
The idea is to start `fun` in a different process. `p` is a process handler that you can control. And then, we put a loop to check file `kill.txt` to see if kill command 'Y' is in there. If yes, then it call `p.terminate()`. The process will then get killed and continue to do next things.

Hope this helps.